# How to create an instance of a View by Uri

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Let's say I've this path **/Views/LoginView.xaml**, How can I create an instance of a View by a specified Uri in Silverlight?

**Edit:** I'm working on a project which is completely developed by another developers. What I want to do is a simple logging system which able to log each View visited by users. There are one frame in MainPage and a class which is responsible to handle requests to Pages. Class has a reference to MainPage and its Frame and has a method to navigate to specific Page by given Path. I know I've path here to log that request, but its just a path, I want to have an instance of that page to get its title and log that title instead of its path.

Comment: Is it a valid path, does your application contain "Views" directory and a "LoginView.xaml" under it ?

Comment: @prthrokz Yes it is a valid path.

Comment: I am not able to understand the purpose here cleary, can you please explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve, because if the xaml file exists you already have a LoginView class created in the code behind that can be instantiated by a simple constructor call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you need to create an instance of a class given the class name. This can be achieved using Reflection and more specifically [Activator.CreateInstance(string className)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)

You can extract the class name from the path by using [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)